# How can I get started creating a Java web service?

Tags: java, web-services

I want to create a simple `hello world` java web service.

What tools I need to get started?

What do I need to know to get started deploying this in Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of [Tomcat + axis tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+axis+tutorial). For example, [this blog post](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-axis-tutorial.html) seems to do a reasonable job.

Answer (score 0):

In JEE5 you can just annotate POJOs with annotations to create webservices: http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/websvc-jax-ws.html

Answer (score 0):

I read this tutorial when I stared to learn how to build and consume Java Web Service
http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/websvc/jax-ws.html